# Vim: Set Color/Theme based off time of day

Tags: vim

I have one of those super glossy monitors, so during the day I can see my own reflection better than my code on Dark themes. So I thought it'd be great if I could have a simple `if` switch in my vimrc to set either a dark theme or a light theme based on the time of day.

Alas, I don't know enough about vimrc syntax and googling came up short.

Anyone wanna take a crack at this?

Comment: clarification: do you want the background to change depending on when you started your vim session, or do you want it to change while you're in vim (the clock strikes noon, and your background is a different color).

Comment: I'm fine with the former, but the latter would be neat if you could figure out how.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
if strftime("%H") < 12
  set background=light
else
  set background=dark
endif
```

Obviously you should choose the hour based on your needs

Comment: You can also change your colorscheme easily by adding another line after the set background line i.e. "colorscheme doodle" or whatever your favorite colorscheme that works well with a light/dark background respectively.

Comment: Using ternary operator: `:let &background = strftime("%H") < 17 ? "light" : "dark"`

Comment: Better
`if strftime("%H") >= 5 && strftime("%H") < 18`

Answer (score 5):

Try the [werewolf.vim](https://github.com/jonstoler/werewolf.vim) plugin:

> Werewolf changes your vim colorscheme automatically based on the time of day, allowing you to use a light theme during the day but "transform" to a dark theme once the sun goes down.

If you use often different color schemes, you can set several pairs of light/dark color schemes, and it will automatically switch to the matching scheme.

Answer (score 4):

This is not strictly a Vim answer but you could try to install [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) which adjusts your monitor colours to the time of the day.

Here is a [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD4HGrptwSg). It has a warm yellowish glow during the day, and blueish one during the night.

Disclaimer : I have not tried it myself (but I am tempted).

Comment: I use it (for some time now). It's a bit odd in the beginning, but if you work during the winter when the days are short, and near a desk lamp ... it kinda works. As I said, a bit odd, but somehow I like it.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that this is now an old question with an accepted answer, but if you are looking to achieve the same functionality using `lua` instead of `vimscript`, here is how I accomplished it.

```lua
local hr = tonumber(os.date('%H', os.time()))
if hr > 6 and hr < 21 then -- day between 6am and 9pm
  vim.opt.background = 'light'
else -- night
  vim.opt.background = 'dark'
end
```

Note that this answer assumes that your preferred color scheme supports `light` and `dark` backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can source a .vimrc.local in your vimrc. Then you could use cron to overwrite that file according to the time of day. no scripting :-)

Answer (score 1):

My [night-and-day](https://github.com/nightsense/night-and-day) plugin is a "vim theme scheduler". You can divide the day into any number of intervals and assign a theme to each. Themes will automatically change if vim is open when a new interval begins.

Comment: The plugin repo is now archived in GitHub. It might be best to avoid it if it's no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out another way of changing color and background

```
exe 'colo' ((strftime('%H') % 18) >= 6 ? 'gruvbox' : 'kolor')
exe 'set background='. ((strftime('%H') % 18) >= 6 ? 'light' : 'dark')
```

Using the rest of division gives more control over the time I want to change background. We can use this shell loop to see why:

```
for ((i=1;i<=23;i++)){
 echo "Rest of dividing $ i by 18 equal to:  $(( $i % 18 ))"
}
```

If I use something like <14, instead of the rest of the division, what happens is that after midnight my color scheme changes to "light". So I make the comparison of the rest of the division of the hour by 6.